# Trackball w/ 4 buttons: how to remap one of buttons to double click?

Tags: xorg, mouse, input

I've got Kensington Slimblade trackball which I've used at my workplace on Windows for past several years.

Today it moved to my house and I'm curious if I'm able to configure mouse buttons with something.

Xev told me that mouse buttons that are pressed when I click on different buttons are:

```
1. Button 1, Button 2 - standard left/right mouse button
2. Button 3 - this works as standard middle mouse button
3. Button 8 - which works strange somehow.
```

What I want to achieve is to have Button 8 interpreted as double mouse-click.

Is this possible somehow? If it's important, I'm running KDE.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue but with the standard 4 button expert mouse trackball from Kensington. This is on my todo and it sounds like it works alright. The trick is to start a custom script and start it as a background process during login.

This is your best bet IMO:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MouseCustomizations

```
gedit ~/.xbindkeysrc

"/usr/bin/xte 'mouseup Y' 'mouseclick 1' 'mouseclick 1' &amp;"
b:Y
```

OR

```
"/usr/bin/xte 'mouseclick 1' 'mouseclick 1' &amp;"
b:Y + Release
```

Then

```
xbindkeys -n -v
```

Now debug your buttons and configs with the output of the last command in a terminal. There isn't a GUI to do this for you. Welcome to Linux... text editors are your friend.